# What is the difference between "cpu/mem-loads/pp" and "cpu/mem-loads/"?

Tags: linux, performance, perf

I read the manual of `perf list`, and find the following `PMU` event definitions of `memory load/store`:

```
mem-loads OR cpu/mem-loads/                        [Kernel PMU event]
mem-stores OR cpu/mem-stores/                      [Kernel PMU event]
```

But I always read `perf` script which uses "`cpu/mem-loads/pp`" instead of "`cpu/mem-loads/`". What is the difference between them? Are they the same thing? I have tried to google the answers, but can't find the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `p` modifier stands for `precise level` When doing sampling, it used to indicate the skid you tolerate: how far can be t reported instruction from the effective instructions that generated the sample. `pp` means that the SAMPLE_IP is requested to have 0 skid. In other word, when you do memory accesses sampling, you want to know exactly which instruction generated the access.

See `man perf list`:

```
p - precise level
....
       The p modifier can be used for specifying how precise the instruction address should be. The p modifier can be specified multiple times:

           0 - SAMPLE_IP can have arbitrary skid
           1 - SAMPLE_IP must have constant skid
           2 - SAMPLE_IP requested to have 0 skid
           3 - SAMPLE_IP must have 0 skid

       For Intel systems precise event sampling is implemented with PEBS which supports up to precise-level 2.

       On AMD systems it is implemented using IBS (up to precise-level 2). The precise modifier works with event types 0x76 (cpu-cycles, CPU clocks not halted) and 0xC1 (micro-ops
       retired). Both events map to IBS execution sampling (IBS op) with the IBS Op Counter Control bit (IbsOpCntCtl) set respectively (see AMD64 Architecture Programmer’s Manual Volume
       2: System Programming, 13.3 Instruction-Based Sampling). Examples to use IBS:

           perf record -a -e cpu-cycles:p ...    # use ibs op counting cycles
           perf record -a -e r076:p ...          # same as -e cpu-cycles:p
           perf record -a -e r0C1:p ...          # use ibs op counting micro-ops
```