# What does this sentence mean in the context of perf tool: "Supports address when precise (Precise event)"?

Tags: linux, profiling, perf, memory-profiling, intel-pmu

This line appears under memory events in perf tool.
CPU: Intel Xeon Gold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Precise" events mean using PEBS instead of the traditional firing an interrupt when the counter overflows.  Instead it writes a sample in a buffer to be collected later, so it can attribute it to the right instruction without pipeline / retirement effects delaying it (e.g. waiting until the currently-last instruction retires, I think to ensure forward progress, causing a "skid").

The PEBS buffer also gives it a place to put additional data, like an address associated with the event that triggered recording a sample.

https://easyperf.net/blog/2018/06/08/Advanced-profiling-topics-PEBS-and-LBR#processor-event-based-sampling-pebs

Also related with discussion about or details of PEBS and how `perf` uses it for `event:pp` -

- [Good resources on how to program PEBS (Precise event based sampling) counters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218275/good-resources-on-how-to-program-pebs-precise-event-based-sampling-counters)
- [What is the difference between "cpu/mem-loads/pp" and "cpu/mem-loads/"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358001/what-is-the-difference-between-cpu-mem-loads-pp-and-cpu-mem-loads)
- [Which perf events can use PEBS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166846/which-perf-events-can-use-pebs)
- [Perf shows L1-dcache-load-misses in a block with no memory access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63251365/perf-shows-l1-dcache-load-misses-in-a-block-with-no-memory-access)